# how to add data inside tablayout which is created through JSON?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablelayout

I am trying to make a dynamic tablayout. I am getting values from json and i am able to make tabs but i want to add values(List) inside those tabs.the Values(List) is also in json format. I am not getting how can i achieve it.

this is my json format

```
{ "Categories": [ { "cat_id": "17", "cat_name": "Bridal Costume ", "sub_categories": [] }, { "cat_id": "18", "cat_name": "Jewellery", "sub_categories": [] }, { "cat_id": "19", "cat_name": "Office\/Godown", "sub_categories": [] }, { "cat_id": "20", "cat_name": "House\/Flat", "sub_categories": [] }, { "cat_id": "21", "cat_name": "Car\/Bike", "sub_categories": [] }, { "cat_id": "22", "cat_name": "Events", "sub_categories": [ { "cat_id": "22", "sub_cat_name": "Tent House" } ] }, { "cat_id": "23", "cat_name": "Fancy Dress", "sub_categories": [] }, { "cat_id": "24", "cat_name": "Other", "sub_categories": [ { "cat_id": "24", "sub_cat_name": "Experiences" }, { "cat_id": "24", "sub_cat_name": "Laptop" } ] } ] }
```

In this i am getting `cat_name` as Tab name and `sub_categories` as a Values(List) inside tab.

Here i am receiving value from JSONFormat, After receiving values i am sending those values to Fragment parentclass. which is declare below

```
public void detail(){
        String  category = null,cat_img,cat_id = null,sub_cat = null,s_name = null;
        JSONObject c = null;
        try {

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            JSONArray Jarray  = object.getJSONArray("Categories");

            for(int i=0;i<Jarray.length();i++){
                 c = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONArray moreDetails = c.getJSONArray("sub_categories");
                category = c.getString("cat_name");

                cat_id = c.getString("cat_id");
                sub_cat = c.getString("sub_categories");

                fragmentParent.addPage(category,cat_id);


                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < moreDetails.length(); i2++) {

                   JSONObject detail = moreDetails.getJSONObject(i2);
                   s_name = detail.getString("sub_cat_name");
                    String s_id = detail.getString("cat_id");
                    fragmentParent.addlist(s_name,s_id);
                   Toast.makeText(this, s_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }





            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
```

FragmentParent.class, After receiving values i am send it to FragmentChild Class.

```
public class FragmentParent extends Fragment {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parent, container, false);
        getIDs(view);
        setEvents();
        return view;
    }

    private void getIDs(View view) {
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.my_viewpager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.my_tab_layout);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), getActivity(), viewPager, tabLayout);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    int selectedTabPosition;

    private void setEvents() {

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                super.onTabSelected(tab);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                selectedTabPosition = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                Log.d("Selected", "Selected " + tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                super.onTabUnselected(tab);
                Log.d("Unselected", "Unselected " + tab.getPosition());
            }
        });
    }

    public void addPage(String pagename,String id) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("data", pagename);
        bundle.putString("c_id", id);
        FragmentChild fragmentChild = new FragmentChild();
        fragmentChild.setArguments(bundle);
        adapter.addFrag(fragmentChild, pagename);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (adapter.getCount() > 0) tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(adapter.getCount() - 1);
        setupTabLayout();
    }

    public void addlist(String listname,String id) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("list_name", listname);
        bundle.putString("s_id", id);

    }

    public void setupTabLayout() {
        selectedTabPosition = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(adapter.getTabView(i));
        }
    }
}
```

And this the FragmentChild Class where i am getting and showing the values inside tabs

FragmentChild.class

```
public class FragmentChild extends Fragment {
    String childname,img_name,cid,s_list,s_id;
    TextView textViewChildName;
    EditText editText;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, container, false);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        childname = bundle.getString("data");
        img_name = bundle.getString("gmi");
        cid = bundle.getString("c_id");
        s_list = bundle.getString("list_name");
        s_id = bundle.getString("s_id");
        getIDs(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void getIDs(View view) {
        textViewChildName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewChild);
        textViewChildName.setText(childname+"-"+cid);

    }


}
```

This is my Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `addlist` method for sub categories puts values in new `Bundle` which didn't use anywhere. Guess it would be better to create `fragmentParent.addPage` function with unnecessary `Bundle` parameter, that should be added to `fragmentChild.setArguments(bundle)` call.